# How to generate a method on an annotated class?

Tags: java, annotations, processor

I wanna learn and have fun with annotations. Here is my use case: I have got a bunch of classes who basically have the same role: validate a video URL against a regex (1 method) and return the corresponding embedded HTML (another method).

The thing is the validation method is always the same. I could of course use inheritance, but I would like if it is possible to create an annotation like this:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.??)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface VideoProvider {
        String regex();
        int group() default 1;
}
```

Processed like that:

```
//processor class
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
        RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
    for (TypeElement annotation : annotations) {
        for (Element e :    roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(annotation)) {
            if (e.getKind().isClass()) {
                //?????
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The idea would be to dynamically change the annotated classes to inject a method that performs the validation.
Is that feasible ?

Thanks in advance!

Rolf

Comment: You can add methods to classes (many frameworks do that). Check [javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) about how to do bytecode manipulation

Comment: This is a contrived example of using annotations, when there is a much better idiomatic way with an `Abstract` class. I would find a more appropriate problem to solve with annotations.

Comment: Yep, you are right. I just wanted to learn how to use it, but the usecase was indeed not really adequate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at using java's [Proxy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class you cglib [Enhancer](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/cglib/proxy/Enhancer.html) class. Both solutions allow you to proxy a class and over take any method.

Comment: thanks for the link. I however fail to understand how to get the InvocationHandler needed for the Proxy instanciation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing it wrong---

But if you really want to implement this with annotation processing at compile time, you should look at the [Pluggable Annotation Processing API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javac/index.html)

This is specifically for adding annotation-driven extensions to the compilation process, to do things like automatically adding methods.

Comment: Hummm, if you can tell me about what is wrong a bit more accurately, I'd be glad :)

Comment: @Rolf -- I don't think you need to add a method at compile time--  I think a common inherited or static method could use the annotation data at runtime to do what you need.  It could be I'm underestimating the complexity of the problem, though.

Comment: Basically, I just would have used a common interface or parent class and define the validation method there, no need of any annotations.

About the static method that would use the annotation data, isn't it exactly what the annotation processor is supposed to do ? 
It's just I don't see how to complete the code to get to the class and add a method in there...

The "compile-time" is absolutely not an obligation by the way.